# Django: define own form field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

i wrote a form field like this

//forms.py

```
hostAdress = forms.CharField(required = False,
                             label = ('#content'),
                             initial = ('#content'))
adminHostAdress = hostAdress
userHostAdress = hostAdress
```

It is displayed correctly, but when a want to save the form, i come to the form back with the filled fields and nothing else happens.

When i write

```
adminHostAdress = forms.CharField(required = False,
                                  label = ('#content'),
                                  initial = ('#content'))
userHostAdress = forms.CharField(required = False,
                                 label = ('#content'),
                                 initial = ('#content'))
```

all works, but i repeat myself and i have more of these fields i want to write once.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is simply assigning the same `CharField` to two separate form variables, so essentially they are sharing the same instance of the Django form field. If you prefer, you could try something like the following:

```
class MyForm(forms.Forms):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in ["adminHostAdress", "userHostAdress", ...]:
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(
                required = False,
                label = ('#content'),
                initial = ('#content'))
```

but this is less readable IMO and not particularly saving you much time.

Comment: ok, thats nasty ;) is there no way to get two seperate instances of the form field, easily?